# how to abort crash in c++

Tags: c++, abort

Considering the following code :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
int main(){

int* ptr;
ptr = new int(3);

int* stock = *&*&ptr;


ptr = nullptr;
cout << *stock<< endl;

cout << *ptr << endl;


}
```

that declares a pointer that allocates dynamic memory.
when another var stocks the adress of the memory.
Then, the pointer is deleted but the memory is not erased.

You can still access the memory using the copy of the pointer.
If you then try to access the memory using the pointer, the programs crashes.
I would like to know, if it is possible, knowing that the program will crash, to make a function that : in case of crash, stop the program from closing, and just cout << "some message".

thank you

ps: i know that crash means "unrecoverable error", so my question is more a creative nature.

Comment: Technically, every case, where crash _may_ occur, it is undefined behavior, so _crash_ is just one of the possibilities of what _may_ happen.

Comment: You have `null'd` the `ptr`, but not `free'd` the memory.  This is not a crashable event, just a logic error. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: this line does not do what you think it does: `int* stock = *&ptr;`

Comment: I'm thinking that there is no way to do this, short of using some system calls.

Comment: _"i know that crash means 'unrecoverable error', so my question is more a creative nature."_ I'm not following this. You already know you can't do this, so what sort of creativity do you seek? Magic?

Comment: Thats funny that this forum is called stack overflow and nobody actually brought the idea of Buffer overflow. I mean, buffer overflow isnt a way to exploit such segmentation fault issues to actually get over a system?

Comment: @dandecasa We are usually trying to get productive, non-malicious programming work done around here, so no one will suggest you write an overflow or use after free exploit to recover from a crash. That would just be a terrible idea.

Comment: Well, i just ask this for learning purposes. My question is only to understand the type of procedures that would allow this kind of behavior. I think this can be a diverse and interesting subject and not a duplicate question.

Comment: Your edit should push your question in the reopen queue, so the community will review my closevote. I'm confident they will agree though.